# handle a template in angular 4

Tags: angular, templates

I am new to Angular 4 and would like to know how to use this function to handle a login form

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
  $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
   });
```

Comment: That code looks like jQuery code, why would you like to use that in angular? Try reading the documentation on how forms work on angular https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your example is `jQuery` code. It's not recommended to access the DOM directly in angular or use a library which does so. That's because you would cheat on angulars lifecycle and probably destroy the cross-platform compatibility.

You can build the form with angular: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

And create the animations with `CSS` or with the angular animations module: https://angular.io/guide/animations